# Load external HTML file with PHP and filter content jQuery-like

Tags: php, jquery, html, filter, external

I would like to extract data about an item from several shops, let's use this [item](http://de.farnell.com/ls-research/001-0009/antenne-dipol-2dbi-2-4-5-5ghz/dp/2324806) as an example (in fact this shop provides a JSON API, but many other don't).

When you inspect this page you'll notice that you can find important data like the price for different quantities in a HTML element like `<table id="otherquantites">`.

With jQuery you could easily grab this element just by calling `$("table#otherquantites")`. Is there a similar way to get this element by using methods from PHP? Of course you could just load the HTML into a DOMDocument and iterate through all the elements, but is there something that works more like the jQuery selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've PHP simple html parser library, its very powerful. check it out
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/